# implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_ifstream

Tags: c++

I am required to use iostream in multiple classes for a project and I am getting this error. I have tried to add inputStream elsewhere but I am not entirely sure what the problem is. (I am including iostream in the header).

```
g++    -c -o Agency.o Agency.cpp
Agency.cpp:48:19: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
    std::ifstream inputStream;
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:131:32: note: 
      template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_ifstream;
                               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Agency.o] Error 1
```

Any tips? (This is in c++) The code is below:

```
void Agency::readAllData(Agency& agency, char *file) {
int i = 0;
char ch;
int tSensors = 0;

char Name[NAME_LENGTHS];
int ZIP[ZIP_LENGTH];

int Year;
char Make[NAME_LENGTHS];
char Model[NAME_LENGTHS];
float Price;
char sensorName[NAME_LENGTHS];
bool bAvailable;
char Owner[NAME_LENGTHS];

char strGPS[4] = "gps";
char strCamera[7] = "camera";
char strLidar[6] = "lidar";
char strRadar[6] = "radar";

std::ifstream inputStream;
inputStream.open(file);

// Read in information
Cars *inventory = agency.inventory;
Sensor *sensors = inventory->getSensors();
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `#include <fstream>`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  The code you posted has no chance to compile - there's no definition of type `Agency`, for a start.  Reduce your code to the *smallest* possible program that demonstrates the issue, and we might be able to answer it.